# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found

Tags: php, validation, error-handling, wordpress, preg-match

I am trying to resolve an issue I have been having with one of my wordpress plugins.

This is line 666

```
function isUrl($url)
{
    return preg_match("^http:\/\/[-0-9a-z\._]+.*$/i", trim( $url ));
}
```

What are your inputs on how I can resolve this warning? It's quite irritating. I can't figure it out and I've tried, researched everything!

Answer (score 6):

`/` is missing. `preg_match('/pattern/',$string);`

```
preg_match("/^http:\/\/[-0-9a-z\._]+.*$/i", trim( $url ));
```

Comment: if(preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_REQUEST['email'])!=1)

Answer (score 3):

As it has been said in other answers, you have to use delimiters arround the regex. You have also the possibility to use another character than `/` to avoid escaping them:

```
return preg_match("~^http://[-0-9a-z._]+.*$~i", trim( $url ));
```

And you could use `\w` that is shortcut of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`:

```
return preg_match("~^http://[-\w.]+.*$~", trim( $url ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex needs a delimiter around it, e.g. /

```
 return preg_match("/^http:\/\/[-0-9a-z\._]+.*$/i", trim( $url ));
```

This delimiter can be different characters but it must be the same before and after your regex. You could e.g. also do this

```
~regex~
```

or

```
#regex#
```

The advantage is, use a delimiter that you don't have inside the regex. If you use / as delimiter and want to match "/" you have to escape it inside the regex ///, if you change the delimiter you could do #/# to match a "/"